# SharePoint Online chart

Tags: sharepoint, charts, sharepoint-online

I would like to display a graph on the home page of my sharepoint online site. I can add in a quick chart but it does not fit my requirements.

Basically, I have a task logger where i log all incoming tasks, they are assigned a status - closed, completed, in progress, on hold, and pending. 
I would like to display this visually on the home page so we can see how many tasks per status.

I think the x axis would the status and the y axis would be the value.

I'm not sure how to achieve this? i've seen multiple examples of coding for this but being inexperienced in coding, i'm not sure how to amend or adapt the codes for my requirements.

If someone could please provide a solution or have any ideas, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the solution below from GitHub to achieve it.

[Modern Charts](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-modern-charts)

Or we can use [modern script editor web part](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor) with chart js plugin and REST API to achieve your requirement.

In classic site page, we can use script/content editor web part with custom JavaScript code to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

If You don't plan to code the solution I would suggest two different then quick chart webpart approaches:

1. File Viewer webpart - You could create some excel file to store all Your task list there. This file could be stored on some document library. The excel file could have data in one tab and chart in other. Using File viewer You could add this excel file on any SharePoint page. On one Page You could present the tab to change data (tasks), on other the tab that has the chart. I know..a bit of a workaround but this is one of the simplest solutions I thought of without coding :)
2. Power BI- this tool for sure may will fit any needs as in this tool You may do almost anything. Of Course You need Power BI server for this. You may create any chart/report with this also from data taken directly from SharePoint

Hope this will be of any help to You

Comment: Thanks Adam. I would love to add coding, i've seen a few great examples i'm just not sure how to amend the code or where to start? I found this link https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-list-formatting/tree/master/view-samples/bar-graph-format

Comment: Would you be able to assist in pointing me in the right direction on how to possibly amend this code to add to my list? If not, i appreciate your suggestions above Thank you :)